# What does this huge X mean that is written like the sigma notation?

Tags: notation

I hope that you will not mind if I do not explain the background of this formula. The problem which I encounter is probably a simple one: What does the huge $\large \times$ mean and why is it written like a sigma? I had no clue how to search for this.

My understanding is: $(l_1, ..., l_{|M|})$ is a set that is defined by counting from $j$ up to $|M|$ and that projects on $\mathbb{R}$ while using $r(m_i, m_j)$ as a function for $l_j$.

Is that correct?

Thank you very much!

$$\large{L_i=(l_1, \ldots l_{|M|})\in \mathop{\huge \times}^{|M|}_{j=1}\Bbb R, \,l_j=r(m_i, m_j)}$$

Comment: looks like an |M|-fold cartesian product. I haven't seen that notation before, though.

Comment: Yes, indeed, a Cartesian product.  There is some fixed underlying function $r:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, and $L_i$ is just the ordered set of images $l_j=r(m_i,m_j)$ ocurring in the $j$-th component of $L_i$.  For fixed $i$, $m_i$ is also fixed, while $m_j$ varies.

Comment: Git Gud, thank you for silently improving my notation :-) I stumbled upon it when reading a text about pearson correlation coefficient. Pairs of $m_i$ are compared with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably an $|M|$-fold Cartesian product. [This link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28150/how-can-i-get-a-big-cross-to-denote-a-generalized-cartesian-product) to the TeX stackexchange supports this interpretation.

Comment: $$\Pi_{j=1}^{|M|}$$ is an alternative notation